# NSOutlineView moveItem() and reloadItem() doesn't work

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView. I've set the delegate and data source. It displays all data correctly after I do `outlineView.reloadData()`

You could picture my outline view like this:

> **Room A**
>
>        - Ash
>        - Brock
>   **Room B**
>
>        - Misty
>        - Professor Oak

I do some editing to the data (not to the outlineView) and move "Misty" to Room A.

> **Room A**
>
>        - Ash
>        - Brock
>        - Misty
>   **Room B**
>
>        - Professor Oak

After I do `outlineView.reloadData()`, it shows the updated data correctly.

Then, I change

`outlineView.reloadData()`

with

`outlineView.moveItem(at: 0, inParent: room[1], to: 2, inParent: room[0])`

But nothing happens. I checked the data source, and the data source wasn't called. It's only called if I do `outlineView.reloadData()`.

I also tried to do `outlineView.reloadItem()` and it also didn't work.

Any idea why `outlineView.moveItem()` doesn't work?

Comment: Why should the outline view call the data source? The data of the items don't change. I tried this (as a Swift exercise, item is a Swift class) and `moveItem()` does work, with animation.

Comment: In my case, I have to add Hashable protocol. Is your class conformed to Hashable protocol?

Comment: I tried and it works, even when all objects return the same hash value. `hashValue` isn't called. Can you reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe how unreliable Cocoa / Appkit framework is compared to UIKit.

The reason why the `moveItem()` doesn't work is because the NSOutlineView only supports Objective-C NSObject. You can't use plain Swift class for the NSOutlineView's item object.

Comment: Note: `NSOutlineView` does support Swift objects. You can use a plain Swift class for the `NSOutlineView`'s item object.